# How many times can you pillage the same province in Blood Rage?

Tags: blood-rage

In Blood Rage, one of the Clan upgrade cards from the second age is Tyr's Challenge, which states, "As your action, you may pay 2 rage to "repillage" an already pillaged province."
In a recent game experience, a player repeatedly used that card in the center Yggdrasil province, which offers 3 stat increases on a success.  My question is, how many times can a player "repillage" a province?

Answer (score 8):

**As much as they have rage to do so.**

From the [official FAQ on CMON's site](https://cmon-files.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/assets_item/resource/31/Blood_Rage_FAQ_1.1.pdf):

> **Q. Does Tyr’s Challenge (*pay 2 rage to repillage*) allow a player to gain the pillage token reward more than once in the same age?**
>
> A. Yes, with Tyr’s Challenge you can pillage an already pillaged province, as long as you pay 2 Rage every time.